# Use Wolfram Alpha to build an exponential curve that passes through 4 points

Tags: interpolation

How can I build a function using Wolfram Alpha that passes through these 4 points?

```
{0, 100}, {1, 30}, {7, 6}, {28, 3}
```

The result I am seeking is a curve with the shape shown in the image. I don't need much precision - just the shape and those 4 points to be on the curve.

[image]

Comment: In my experience the clearest way to communicate with Wolfram Alpha is often to feed it _Mathematica_ syntax: IMO `FindFit[{{0,100},{1,30},{7,6},{28,3}}, {a*(x+c)^b, a>0, b<0, c>0}, {a,b,c}, x]` gives a good looking fit.

Comment: @eyorble thanks it is really good, but not good enough. E.g. x = 28, this model gets me 1.98 not exact 3 :(

Comment: `WolframAlpha["exponential fit through {0, 100}, {1, 30}, {7, 6}, {28, 3}"]`

Comment: Exact fit just requires more fitting parameters and a bit of figuring out what the limits on them should be: `FindFit[{{0,100},{1,30},{7,6},{28,3}}, {a*(x+c)^b+d, a>0, b<0, c>0.3, d>0}, {a,b,c,d}, x]` gives a fit which has no meaningful residuals.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about W|A, not how to use Mathematica.

Comment: To potential answerers, the question is tagged [tag:interpolation] and state the curve "passes through these 4 points." It does not seem to be about fitting an exponential model, only that the interpolating curve will end up looking somewhat like an exponential.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Actual use of e.g. `Interpolation` with those points will not look much like the result he wants though. To me, fitting does appear to be the better approach, even though the result does not meet the requirement that the curve pass through those points, because it "looks more like" the desired outcome.

Comment: @MarcoB Looks pretty good to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCAWy.png -- I'd only expect only three lines and four points, not dozens, and it's possible that's what the OP has in mind. The image the OP shows just such a plot, connecting data points with lines, a common thing to do, I believe. OTOH, it wouldn't be the first time that a question asked for X but really wanted Y. Though 4  points is rather few for fitting.

Answer (score 3):

```
NonlinearModelFit[{{0, 100}, {1, 30}, {7, 6}, {28, 3}},   a Exp[-b x] + c, {a, b, c}, x]
```

Gives
`4.4939 + 95.5052 E^(-1.32011 x)`
With Residuals:
`{0.000871158, -0.00380506, 1.49683, -1.4939}`
[image]

If you are ok with a linear adjustment to the exponential, you can get a near perfect fit with:

```
NonlinearModelFit[{{0, 100}, {1, 30}, {7, 6}, {28, 3}}, 
 a Exp[-b  x] + c + d x, {{a, 100}, b, {c, 3}, d}, x]
```

(Note reasonable starting guesses for a and c.)

Which gives: `6.99266 + 93.0073 E^(-1.39069 x) - 0.142595 x`
With residuals: `{5.96145*10^-11, -1.69038*10^-11, -8.5266*10^-11, -1.01638*10^-10}`

[image]

Comment: `a Exp[-b (x - x0)] + c` is equivalent to `a2 Exp[-b x] + c` since `a Exp[b*x0]` is a constant.

Comment: @BobHanlon oh right, thanks.  For some reason when I tries that originally it wasn't giving a good fit without an initial guess.  Will fix in above.

Answer (score 2):

With Mathematica you would proceed as described below. I assume that you can do the same with Wolfram Alpha.

You may try "NonLinearModelFit" with the option: "Model->"Newton"" or "Model->"NMinimize"":

```
d = {{0, 100}, {1, 30}, {7, 6}, {28, 3}};
model = c0 + c1 Exp[c2 (x - c3)];
res = NonlinearModelFit[d, model, {c0, c1, c2, c3}, x, Method -> "Newton"]
Plot[res[x], {x, 0, 28}, Epilog -> Point[d], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `c0 + c1 Exp[c2 (x - c3)]` is equivalent to `c0 + c4 Exp[c2 x]` since `c1 Exp[-c2 c3]` is a constant.

Comment: Right, thanks for the hint. I simplified the model.